# JQuery datatable issue

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to create a colors system for every row depending of a value from a column. Im trying to use a function insinde the parameter `createdRow`but when the datatable is draw the colors are the same. It's as if the datatable did not recognize the parameter.

```
oTable = $("#supervisionResultatDepot").dataTable({
    // "sScrollX"       : "100%",
    // "bScrollCollapse": true,
    "oLanguage" : {
        "sProcessing"   : "Traitement en cours...",
        "sLengthMenu"   : "Afficher _MENU_ éléments",
        "sZeroRecords"  : "Aucun élément à afficher",
        "sInfo"         : "Affichage de l'élement _START_ à _END_ sur _TOTAL_ éléments",
        "sInfoEmpty"    : "Affichage de l'élement 0 à 0 sur 0 éléments",
        "sInfoFiltered" : "(filtré de _MAX_ éléments au total)",
        "sInfoPostFix"  : "",
        "sSearch"       : "Rechercher :",
        "sUrl"          : "",
        "oPaginate" : {
            "sFirst" : "Premier",
            "sPrevious" : "Précédent",
            "sNext" : "Suivant",
            "sLast" : "Dernier"
        }
    },
    "createdRow": function(row, data, dataIndex) {
         if (data[3] == "A valider") {        
            $(row).addClass('red-orange');
          }
    },
    "aoColumnDefs" : [ 
    {
        "sClass" : "idDepot",
        "aTargets" : [ 0 ],
        "sName" : "idDepot"
    }, {
        "sClass" : "numDepot",
        "aTargets" : [ 1 ],
        "sName" : "numDepot"
    },{
        "sClass" : "dateDepot",
        "aTargets" : [ 2 ],
        "sName" : "dateDepot",
        'sType' : 'date-fr'
    }, {
        "sClass" : "statutDepot ",
        "aTargets" : [ 3 ],
        "sName" : "statutDepot"
    }, {
        "sClass" : "idContrat",
        "aTargets" : [ 4 ],
        "sName" : "idContrat"
    }, {
        "sClass" : "idContrat",
        "aTargets" : [ 4 ],
        "sName" : "idContrat"
    }, {
        "sClass" : "numPub",
        "aTargets" : [ 5 ],
        "sName" : "numPub"
    }, {
        "sClass" : "titre",
        "aTargets" : [ 6 ],
        "sName" : "titre"
    }, {
        "sClass" : "numParution",
        "aTargets" : [ 7 ],
        "sName" : "numParution"
    }, {
        "sClass" : "typeParution",
        "aTargets" : [ 8 ],
        "sName" : "typeParution"
    }, {
        "sClass" : "nivService",
        "aTargets" : [ 9 ],
        "sName" : "nivService"
    }, {
        "sClass" : "bdcSafran",
        "aTargets" : [ 10 ],
        "sName" : "bdcSafran"
    },  {
        "sClass" : "nbExDecla",
        "aTargets" : [ 11 ],
        "sName" : "nbExDecla"
    },  {
        "sClass" : "mtTotHt",
        "aTargets" : [ 12 ],
        "sName" : "mtTotHt"
    },  {
        "sClass" : "idDepotDrl",
        "aTargets" : [ 13 ],
        "sName" : "idDepotDrl"
    }],
    "sZeroRecords" : "Aucun élément à afficher",
    "bJQueryUI" : true,
    "bAutoWidth" : true,
    "sDom" : '<"top">rt<"tablesorterPager"lp><"clear">',
    "iDisplayLength" : 10,
    "aLengthMenu" : [ [ 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, -1 ], [ 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, "Tous" ] ],
    "aoColumns" : [ 
    {
        'sWidth' : '4%'
    },  {
        'sWidth' : '5%'
    },  {
        'sWidth' : '4%'
    }, {
        'sWidth' : '5%'
    }, {
        'sWidth' : '4%'
    }, {
        'sWidth' : '4%'
    }, {
        'sWidth' : '10%'
    }, {
        'sWidth' : '4%'
    }, {
        'sWidth' : '6%'
    }, {
        'sWidth' : '4%'
    }, {
        'sWidth' : '6%'
    }, {
        'sWidth' : '6%'
    }, {
        'sWidth' : '4%'
    }, {
        'sWidth' : '4%'
    }],
    "aaSorting" : [ [ 2, 'asc' ] ],
    "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers"
});
```

Comment: Is the class added to the corresponding row? Check your source code, could be a CSS problem as well since you add a class red-orange, you would have to specify a style for the class or write something like this:  $(row).css('background-color', 'red');

Comment: `.red-orange{ background-color: orange !important; }` try `!important` keyword at the end of `CSS`.

Comment: i found the problem, its not 'createdRow' ,it's 'fnCreatedRow'

Comment: Seems strange, I use createdRow a lot, but I access my property value using the property's name not index. As in `if(data.statutDepot == "A valider")`. Do you know which version of DataTables you are using?